# XC9 Entity Composer: child-views and tagged templates not shown in Sitecore Content Editor

Tags: sitecore-commerce

When using the Entity Composer functionality in the XC9 Business Tools I noticed that:

- a sellable item child-view is (after updating templates) not shown in the Sitecore Content Editor (Commerce > Catalog Management > Catalogs)
- a entity composed template added to a sellable item by tag is (after updating templates) not shown in the Sitecore Content Editor (Commerce > Catalog Management > Catalogs)

Adding a entity template by item definition does result in showing the template in the Sitecore Content Editor.

Should entity templates work for child-views and adding by tag as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After contacting Sitecore support, it turns out that with Sitecore XC9 update-2 the child-views and tagged templates do not work with the current Sitecore Dataprovider. This will be fixed in a later release (reference #40876).

Conclusion, for the moment (with XC9 update-2) you should link template by Item Definition.